# Does the strategy pattern incur more overhead than a switch statement?

Tags: java, switch-statement, javac, strategy-pattern, enum-map

I have a switch statement that currently handles around 20 different numerical event types. The event ID ranges from 1000-5000. The `switch` statement is becoming more difficult to maintain and read.

My idea is to put each event type into its own class and then store it into an `EnumMap`. This approach will make the code maintainable and easier to read but what am I really sacrificing here?

Each client (ranging from 1000-5000 clients) that connects will have its own initialization of this `EnumMap` along with the all the event type classes. This is a lot of overhead, is it not?

In regards to performance, is there any downside to using an `EnumMap` over a `switch`? Does `javac` compile them similarly? There will be times where every millisecond counts.

Comment: *"Each client (ranging from 1000-5000 clients) that connects will have its own initialization of this EnumMap along with the all the event type classes"* Why? Can't you have a single shared copy and pass the client-specific information (`this` or whatever) to the implementations stored in the map?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes I could. Making the `EnumMap` static is something I was considering as well and I suppose that addresses my overhead questions.